# Can't log in to Drupal 6 site

Tags: php, authentication, drupal-6

I am developing a custom theme for our Drupal based website, and I needed to log out to check on the look of the site for an anonymous user.

Once I logged out, I could not log back in. I tried several admin accounts, on several computers, and none of them worked.

Thankfully, my laptop loads the website logged in as admin. From there, I can clear the cache (as well as with drush), and I can see the server logs as well.

Interestingly enough, when I attempt to log in as a user, the logs show that a session has been opened for that person, but the browser on the user side just refreshes back to the home page and does not log the person in.

My admin skin is set to Bluemarine, so unfortunately that isn't the issue. I also changed the sites theme to Garland, and I still have no luck logging in with any other login or computer.

I am thinking my next step will be to revert to an earlier version. Although, it would be great to find out what I did to break it so I don't do it again.

Comment: To get a reply, you should report which modules you enabled. It's not a Drupal core issue, or that would have been already resolved (considering the number of users using Drupal for their web sites).

Answer (score 0):

try surfing to http://your_domain/user
it will take you to the login page.